# Completely remove MySQL from macbook pro

Tags: macos, mysql, uninstall

Im prety sure i completely removed mysql from my system, except for one thing. When i type mysql in the command line i get this

```
bash: /opt/local/bin/mysql5: No such file or directory
```

How is it still recognizing where it thinks mysql should be? I'm trying to build it myself in /usr/local, and when i do install it there, i still get that error message for it looking for it in opt/local.

Comment: ok i typed unalias mysql and it worked.  Where are aliases stored ?
Is there an .aliases file somewhere?

Comment: replacing the [mac-os] tag with the [osx] tag under the assumption that you are *not* running Mac OS 9 or earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Type

```
type mysql
```

on the command line; this will tell you where bash found mysql.

It might be that mysql's old path is simply cached. Try opening a new terminal first.

*Update:* If type tells you mysql is aliased to some place unter /opt/, then you'll have to remove the alias. Aliases have to be defined in the shell's startup files (if they were not set manually). So look through bash's startup files to find the alias setting. Bash has several startup files (see the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files)), look for one of:

- profile
- bashrc
- bash_profile

They can either be in the user's home dir (name prepended with a .), or under /etc/ (under Linux, dunno where Mac OS X puts them).

Comment: i tried restarting the machine and it still happens. I get this
    $ type mysql
    mysql is aliased to `/opt/local/bin/mysql5'

Comment: If mysql is aliased as your comment suggests, the following should find it:

    `grep -riI mysql ~`

It searches all the text files in (and under) your home directory for the text.

Answer (score 0):

Alaises can be stored in a variety of locations.  Within .profile, /etc/profile or any file that maybe sourced by the shell.  Simply examine them by typing 'alias' at a system prompt.

1. If you can not find the source for
   the alias - then from command line -
   'unalias mysql'
2. perform your install
3. then create a new/updated alias in
   your own ~/.bashrc (the '~'
   represents your home directory)

---